# Set & Get input value in web browser in c#

Tags: c#

I just try to understand the concept of in web browser control c# win app.

I have created a Windows app with web browser control. I have called a web page (which is my own) and try to set value in the web page from my app.

When i try with Google

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com/search?q=" + "C#");
```

it works fine.

When i try in this way, it is not working.

```
HtmlElement textArea = webBrowser1.Document.All["q"];
textArea.InnerText = "dsfs";
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? Do you want to set a value for query string parameter "q" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to wait for the `WebBrowser` to load before you access it (otherwise `Document` will be null until loaded) - subscribe a `DocumentCompleted` event handler for this. Also [`Document.All["q"]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.all(v=vs.110).aspx) will return the [first element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4b70was(v=vs.110).aspx) with the name "q".

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431004");
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (o, args) =>
{
    var ele = webBrowser1.Document.All["q"];
    if (ele.TagName.ToLower() == "input")
    {
        ele.InnerText = "dsfs";
    }
};
```

If you want to change more than one such element, or if you want to locate elements by Id, Tag name etc, you will need to iterate the collection:

```
foreach (HtmlElement ele in webBrowser1.Document.All)
{
    if (ele.TagName.ToLower() == "input")
    {
        ele.InnerText = "dsfs";
    }
}
```